# Convert SVG code to graphic in R Markdown

Tags: r, svg, r-markdown

Is there anyway to take code such as the following, which produces a simple circle, and produce the resulting image when knitted to HTML?

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#757575" /></svg>
```

For reference as to why I have code rather than images, this SVG is extract from JSON blobs as text. If I save it to a text file with .svg extension, it can open fine. The end result of this code would be a shiny app that displays the SVG from various JSON blobs.

EDIT: Stéphane Laurent's solution (below) worked. I failed to explain that this SVG would be inside a data frame, which presented another challenge in rendering. However, their answer led me to this:

````
```{r}
tribble(~id, ~svg,
        1, '<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#757575" /></svg>',
  2, '<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#757575" /></svg>') %>%
  knitr::kable(escape = F) %>%
        kableExtra::kable_styling()
````

Comment: The `rsvg` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rsvg/index.html) may be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned by **Limey**, you can use the **rsvg** package to convert to **png**. But you can simply paste the **svg** tag in the Rmarkdown file, quality is better than **png**:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Stéphane Laurent"
date: '2022-05-20'
output: html_document
---

<svg height="100" width="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="#757575" /></svg>
```

**Note:** *Do not indent the code*, otherwise it will be rendered as a code block.

[image]